# PHPOffice Word generator problem when opening file

Tags: php, phpword

Whenever I try to download a file generated by PHPWord, this error pops up

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download source from here - "https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord" or also prefar this one 'https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/phpword/latest/phpword.pdf'

```
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpword, 'Word2007');
$filename = 'helloWorld'.date("h:i:s").'.docx';
$objWriter->save($filename);
```

May be issue with your ms word. try with online view or other way.

Try also below one

1.Add `setCompatibility()` before createWriter()

```
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setCompatibility(false);
```

2. Add `exit;` after the `save()`

```
// XML Writer compatibility
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setCompatibility(false);

    // Saving the document as OOXML file...
    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
    ob_clean();
    $objWriter->save('php://output');

    exit;
```

Just add ob_clean(); before output it!